# P4V: Get Previous Revisions For File in Changelist X does not work for large changelists

Tags: perforce, p4v

On right clicking a submitted changelist and clicking on "Get Previous Revisions For File in Changelist xyz", I see files update for small changelists, but not for very large ones (such as one with 15000+ files). I don't see a buffering sign indicating work in progress either.

Is there another way to get the previous revision of all files in a large changelist?

Comment: Do you need to specifically get only the files that were in that changelist?  The more common (and easier) use case is to simply sync the workspace (or folder within the workspace) to the previous changelist.  If the changelist touched every single file (which seems likely based on your description) it's the same effect either way, but syncing everything at once makes it a much simpler/faster operation.

Comment: The changelist did not touch all the files in the codebase

Comment: Would there be any harm in just syncing everything to the prior changelist, regardless?  Individually syncing files to different changelists, while something that Perforce makes possible, is kind of a "smell" if you're doing it on a large scale.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this from the command line (which should work regardless of the size of the changelist) would be:

```
p4 -F %depotFile%@XYY files @=XYZ | p4 -x - sync
```

where `XYZ` is the changelist with all the files and `XYY` is `XYZ`-1.

Note that in most cases the better option is to simply do:

```
p4 sync @XYY
```

which you can also do directly from P4V by just clicking the previous changelist and syncing it.